# How to set authSource in MongoDB ODBC driver?

Tags: mongodb, odbc, dsn

I'm trying to set up a System DSN with MongoDB ODBC driver (v1.4.2) on Windows 10 but connection always fails.
I'm guessing it's because I need to set up the authSource but I don't know how.

In their documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/bi-connector/master/tutorial/create-system-dsn/), it says to pass it on with the username like this:

```
grace?source=admin
```

But I tried that and it didn't work either.

[Here's how I'm doing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbFM7.png)

[the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJkwA.png) = "Lost connection to MySQL server at reading initial communication packet"

Comment: What do the server logs say?

Comment: Please don't paste images, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3027266

Comment: I guess you have to set in in "database" field. If the authentication database is different to the "data" database then you need to specify in your statements, e.g. `db.getSiblingDB("MyDB").collection.find(...)`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit oh sorry, didn't know about that. I put the error message in text now. I did try setting in database, didn't work either. =(

Comment: @D.SM I don't have access to the server logs unfortunately, also don't have access to admin database either, I'm guessing that's the problem. =(

Comment: Do you have MongoDB running on your premises or in cloud?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit in cloud, and I don't have access to the server. But I could try to request some tweak.

Comment: If someone ends up here with the same issues, the problem was with the server, the MongoDB BI connector wasn't installed there.